# How do I access Firebase Storage emulator hosted images from mobile devices?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I'm getting the public URLs of my images like the below.

```js
const file = admin.storage().bucket().file('...');
await file.makePublic();
file.publicUrl(); // Returns http://localhost:9199/...
```

It returns URLs with the host set to localhost and it makes it impossible to access them from mobile devices.

I tried to replace localhost with my computer IP address but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had to set the port to 0.0.0.0 on the firebase.json file. Then, I can access the images using my IP address instead of localhost.

firebase.json

```json
{
  "emulators": {
    "storage": {
      "host": "0.0.0.0",
      "port": 9199
    },
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```